# DateTime confusion

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a list of DateTimes and I must choose the closest time after DateTime.Now.

```
if(listItem > DateTime.Now)
{
   ...
}
```

```
 Date   Day  Time       Hgt 

07/19   Tue 01:39 AM    0.12 L

07/19   Tue 08:00 AM    3.81 H

07/19   Tue 01:24 PM    0.07 L

07/19   Tue 08:18 PM    4.46 H

07/20   Wed 02:19 AM    -0.01 L

07/20   Wed 08:43 AM    4.01 H

07/20   Wed 02:09 PM    0.0 L

07/20   Wed 09:01 PM    4.58 H
```

My problem is if I check at - 5:24 AM - it will return 1:24 PM as the first time after DateTime.Now.

Comment: How are you loading the times in? i.e. into the listbox

Comment: You must iterate over all dates and find the one which is closer to current date and >, not just the first one you find.

Comment: Yep...I need the Dates for the DateTime.Parse. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
DateTime closest =
    DateTime.Now >= yourListOfDateTimes.Last()
        ? yourListOfDateTimes.Last()
        : DateTime.Now <= yourListOfDateTimes.First()
            ? yourListOfDateTimes.First()
            : yourListOfDateTimes.First(d => d >= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Good use of "?:" Operands.